# When a new item is created, create a folder and two documents inside the folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a two documents (1 and 2) that i would like to have as a template in Sharepoint.
And i have a list in Sharepoint, called Mylist.

Whenever a new item is created, i want a new folder to be created with the name of ColumnA in that list.
And within that folder the two documents have to be created.

The name of document 1 has to be the name of the value of Colum B from Mylist.
The name of document 2 has to be the value of Column C in the list + the words "Formulier".
How do i do this?

Comment: What Version of SharePoint do you use?

Comment: I use SharePoint 365.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using Microsoft 365, the preferred way to do this will be using Power Automate (Flow). You can use flow to create a folder and documents from template with a trigger in your list. However creating word documents from template will need premium actions, so you will need to have a proper plan for its subscription.

[Create a folder in SharePoint](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Community-Blog/MS-Flow-Create-new-folder-action/ba-p/355632)

[Create a document from template](https://karinebosch.wordpress.com/2018/11/08/microsoft-flow-create-a-document-set/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I follow the steps in: http://www.sharepointcorridor.com/2018/05/generate-word-document-from-sharepoint.html  And it is solved.